# How to get all the instances list belongs to all projects in Openstact? In CLI Mode

Tags: openstack-nova

In my current organisation we have 20 Projects in OPenstack so that, I want to get all the instances belongs to all openstack projects with one single command.

Comment: Hi All, Please help me in this.

Answer (score 1):

The command to list all servers across all projects is:
    openstack server list --all

Assuming the account you are running it from has access to all those projects/is domain admin account.